# Excel failling to recognize type of chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have following code to copy all charts on one sheet into another.

Problem is that in spite of the fact that my charts have numeric(timeseries) data for horizontal axis Excel treats it as categorical. I can tell that is does that because it tries to display every single date on the axis( in spite of my code swtiching it to once a month), and once select "Format Axis" I only see fields for Categorical data( I am missing fields like Maximim, Major Unit etc.).

This is the code I am using, to be hones I copeid most of it of some forum but I cannot recall where if I do find it again I'll post a link:

```
Sub CopyCharts(Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet)
    Dim SChart         As ChartObject
    Dim NChart         As ChartObject
    Dim NewSheetNChart As ChartObjects
    Dim ChartTop       As Single
    Dim ChartLeft      As Single
    Dim ChartIndex     As Integer
    Dim ChartSeries    As Series
    Dim XAxis          As Axis

    For Each SChart In Source.ChartObjects
        'Save chart's current position
        ChartTop = SChart.Top
        ChartLeft = SChart.Left

        'Copy and paste the chart
        SChart.Copy
        Target.Paste

        'Find the chart in a new spreadsheet
        ChartIndex = ChartIndex + 1
        Set NewSheetNChart = Target.ChartObjects
        Set NChart = NewSheetNChart(ChartIndex)

        'Align the charts
        NChart.Top = ChartTop
        NChart.Left = ChartLeft

        'Delink sereis from source
        For Each ChartSeries In NChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
            ChartSeries.XValues = ChartSeries.XValues
            ChartSeries.Values = ChartSeries.Values
            ChartSeries.Name = ChartSeries.Name
        Next ChartSeries

        'Set the X axis to correct values
        Set XAxis = NChart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        With XAxis
            .CategoryType = xlTimeScale
            .BaseUnit = xlMonths
            .MajorUnit = 1
        End With
    Next SChart
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the data formatted in the cells you are referencing in the x-axis?

Comment: It is just a numeric value formated as a string

Comment: excuse me formated as a date not a string

Comment: What type of chart are they?  You probably want Scatterplots if you want to format the X-axes like that.

Comment: Actulaly they are plain line graphs, with two series ploted on one axis

Comment: So try switching the type after pasting